# Remove Space before Chapter Title

Tags: spacing, chapters, titlesec

I am quite new to LaTeX and wish to remove some space before the Chapter Headings. I have found the following command that uses the titlesec package, however I wish for the space before to be smaller.

Preamble and loaded packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox, float, graphicx, fancyhdr, lastpage, amsmath, amssymb, newpxmath,bm,lastpage}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}

\usepackage[margin=1.05in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{SOR2221 Assignment}
\rhead{Group 10}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
```

The current spacing looks like the following:
[image]

Comment: Try to replace `3.5ex` with a smaller value

Comment: Thanks, for the help! I didn't realize that I could set it to negative values as well and that seemed to do the trick.